# How to set default NSDragOperation when user is dragging?

Tags: macos, cocoa, drag-and-drop, cursor, icons

I am making a drop & drop code. I used `NSDragOperationGeneric | NSDragOperationMove | NSDragOperationCopy | NSDragOperationLink` mode for all drag & drop code. My problem is the mouse cursor is being displayed as *copy* mode (with "+" icon beside cursor) instead of *plain* mode (without any icon) by default with no modifier key pressed

I want to imitate Finder behavior which moves file by default with no modifier key and copies with option key. So I want to display dragging cursor as plain when user did not press any modifier key.

How can I do this?

Comment: ⌘ explicitly chooses the move action as well, the same (in Finder) as holding down no modifiers. Copy is option/alt/⌥, link (in Finder, make alias) is ⌘⌥. Ctrl doesn't do anything that I know of.

Comment: @PeterHosey Thanks. I fixed wrong keys.